# Upgrade Ubuntu Server leads to fail to access my homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I hosted several websites on AWS EC2. It works fine.

I just upgraded my Ubuntu server with `sudo do-release-upgrade`, and the process of updating seems fine as well.

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
```

However, while I visit `example.com`, it shows the following code rather than a homepage:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I checked the configurations with the help of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page), but still failed to make it right.

**1. My machine did installed PHP and apache.**

```
$ php -version 
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2019 12:07:07) ( NTS )

$ sudo apt-get install apache2
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.11).
```

**2. Add `LoadModule php`**

Add the following line at the end of `apache2.conf`:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
```

**3. Add types**

Append the following codes to `apache2.conf`,

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Bingo, everything goes well:-)

Comment: You might need to reinstall both PHP and Apache to get them to mesh right.

Comment: @aynber, I solved it. Please checked my update.